# Powering 3 sensors from one 5v pin

Tags: pi-4, power

I am powering 3 different sensor (a temperature sensor, an IR transmitter and an IR receiver) on my Pi. I would like to use the same 5V pin to power all three.

I connected a jumper onto the 5v pin, and then split the cable into 3 by soldering them together.

[image]

Questions:

1. Is this a bad idea?
2. Is there a better way of doing this? (See: a pre-made little thing that will do the trick, 1 cable becomes 3, female to male or female to female) Surely lots of people will connect multiple sensors -- there are only 2 5V supplies, and surely people will have 3, 4, 5 sensors often enough?

Comment: There is only a single 5v supply, but has two pins to make it easier to connect to.

Comment: I know. I actually have _three_ very low power devices to connect. I just wanted to simplify the question! I now understand why there are only 5v pins -- normally, prototype boards are made on breadboards, which will make it easy. Or, will make a proper circuit. I just so happen to need a Pi with 3 sensors effectively flying around...

Answer (score 1):

> Questions:
> Is this a bad idea?
> Is there a better way of doing this? (See: a pre-made little thing that will do the trick, 1 cable becomes 3, female to male or female to female) Surely lots of people will connect multiple sensors -- there are only 2 5V supplies, and surely people will have 3, 4, 5 sensors often enough?

1. The only thing that could make this a ***Bad Idea*** is if you're drawing too much current. The number of wires matters not at all - other than perhaps the *messiness* factor.
2. If you are using a solderless breadboard, they *typically* have rails that run the entire length of the breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good idea to share the power pin to me.
It's what I do myself when I want multiple grounds or multiple power lines (and don't want to use a breadboard with its power rails).